# How can I fix "python setup.py egg_info" failed pytorch install error?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pytorch

I am trying to install pytorch from github. I type in
    pip3 install git+pip3 install git+https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git

I am getting this error. I've tried upgrading pip, switch from python 2 to 3, etc.

```
 File "/Users/MYK/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--target', 'install', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j', '4']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
Building wheel torch-1.2.0a0+d4464d3
-- Building version 1.2.0a0+d4464d3
cmake -DBUILD_PYTHON=True -DBUILD_TEST=True -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=  -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS= -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/private/var/folders/xs/xqll03b96p74d6v15mwfvwgw0000gq/T/pip-req-build-ryxkksy0/torch -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/MYK/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS= -DINSTALL_TEST=True -DNUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/Users/MYK/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Users/MYK/anaconda3/bin/python -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/Users/MYK/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/Users/MYK/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib -DTORCH_BUILD_VERSION=1.2.0a0+d4464d3 -DUSE_CUDA=False -DUSE_DISTRIBUTED=True -DUSE_FBGEMM=True -DUSE_NCCL=False -DUSE_NUMPY=True -DUSE_SYSTEM_EIGEN_INSTALL=OFF -DUSE_SYSTEM_NCCL=False /private/var/folders/xs/xqll03b96p74d6v15mwfvwgw0000gq/T/pip-req-build-ryxkksy0
cmake --build . --target install --config Release -- -j 4
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xs/xqll03b96p74d6v15mwfvwgw0000gq/T/pip-req-build-ryxkksy0/

Comment: do you have cmake installed?

Comment: so i installed cmake, new error, updated in post.

Comment: I am guessing that there are still some requirements that are not installed. try using `conda` instead of `pip` to install pytorch, as `conda` is much better at handling requirements of complex libraries

Comment: conda install -c pytorch pytorch 
and then
pip3 install torchvision worked!

Comment: Might not be the best idea to install one using `conda` and the other one using pip. My personal recommendation is to use `conda` as much as possible when dealing with anaconda environments

Comment: oh ok, thanks. I obviously don't know much out these stuff.